# On $\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\mid n\\d<f(n)}}d$ and odd perfect numbers, for $f(n)$ the greatest prime factor or $\operatorname{rad}(n)$, respectively

Tags: nt.number-theory, divisors-multiples, perfect-numbers

First, in this paragraph we remember the definitions/notations for two number theoretic functions, for an integer $m>1$, we denote its greatest prime factor as $\operatorname{gpf}(m)$, and the product of the distinct prime numbers dividing $m$ as $$\operatorname{rad}(m)=\prod_{\substack{p\mid m\\p\text{ prime}}}p,$$
with the definition $\operatorname{rad}(1)=1$ (see it you want the Wikipedia *Radical of an integer* and the corresponding article from MathWorld *Greatest Prime Factor*).

I wondered about if it is possible to set some statement about the following quantities under the assumption that $n$ is an odd perfect number. I am asking about statements concerning some aspect of the divisivility of these integers (if you can deduce some congruence, or maybe something about the greatest common divisor for some one of these quantities and $n$), or well if we can deduce some bound  about these quantities when we assume that $n$ runs over the set of odd perfect numbers. Those definitions are

$$g(n)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\mid n\\d<\operatorname{gpf}(n)}}d\tag{1}$$
and 
$$r(n)=\sum_{\substack{1\leq d\mid n\\d<\operatorname{rad}(n)}}d\,.\tag{2}$$

I don't know if this problem is in the literature, I hope that my question has a good mathematical content for odd perfect numbers (that previous arithmetic functions have a good mathematical content for odd perfect numbers).

> **Question.** We assume that there exist odd perfect numbers. What can be done 
>    about statements concerning the divisivility of $g(n)$ or $r(n)$ and $n$? Can you deduce a remarkable statement (using the theory of odd perfect numbers) about expressions of the type $$\text{lower bound}\leq g(n)\leq\text{upper bound}$$
>   or maybe bounds for the other quantity
>   $$\text{lower bound}\leq r(n)\leq \text{upper bound}?$$
>   **Many thanks.**

You can to invoke/use the theory of odd perfect numbers, and in your expressions for the second question you can express your bounds in terms of $n$ or well in terms of the prime factorization of $n$ (you can express your bounds in terms of the prime numbers and their corresponding exponents, from Euler's theorem for odd perfect numbers).

With *remarkable* in previous question I understand statments that have some mathematical content, that are elaborated from the theory and reasonings/heuristics. Since I think that this question is very difficult after we get some answers for some of those relationships between the defined  arithmetical functions and $n$ I should accept the answer.

Comment: As aside remark, if one wants to do a comparison, one can to calculate the corresponding sums $(1)$ and $(2)$ for $n$ an even perfect number.